# CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc") Library not registered

Tags: excel, vba, acrobat

We are migrating to a new Remote Desktop server. We have a tool that merges one pdf to another pdf. This tool is now encountering an error in this line of code:

```
Set PartDocs(i) = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
```

The error is:

> Run-time error '-2147319779(8002801d)': Automation Error. Library not registered.

I am using MS Excel 2010 and Adobe Acrobat DC is installed and paid.
The Acrobat reference I have is Adobe Acrobat 10.0 Type Library with path C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat 2015\Acrobat\acrobat.tlb

I haven't tried re-installing the Acrobat since we are using PC in the office and has admin restrictions.
I am not sure if this is related to the reference of the VBA or if this is already related to REGISTRY.

We're using Windows 7. And we only have one excel version installed. But we also have Adobe Reader and Distiller installed.

The whole code is working on our previous remote desktop server but now it's encountering an error in the new environment.

Comment: Since it is not a code issue and it worked on another computer it can only be an installation issue. I suggest try to re-install Acrobat (not Reader!).

Comment: This is a re-posting of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55424881/1188513).